# Binary Search Program Not Printing Correct Index

Tags: java, arrays, input, binary, binary-search

I need to create a binary search program where, if the search key is in the array, it returns the largest index i for which a[i] is equal to key, but, otherwise, returns –i where i is the largest index such that a[i] is less than key.

Sample runs would be as follows.

more input.txt
2 3 4 5 6 6 6 7 8 9 11

java BinarySearch input.txt 10

-9

java BinarySearch input.txt 6

6

So far the program will print the correct index for numbers in input file, but it won't print -i when I enter a number not on the list. For instance, it won't print -9 when I enter 10 in the command line; instead, it prints -10.

```
public class BinarySearch{

    public static int search(int key, int [] a, int lo, int hi)
    {  
        int n = a.length;
        
    if (hi >= lo) 
        {
        int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
        if      ((mid == n-1 || key < a[mid+1]) && a[mid] == key) 
        return mid;
        else if (key < a[mid]) 
        return search(key, a, lo, (mid-1));
        else return search(key, a, (mid+1), hi);
        }   
    return -1*lo;
    }
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        In in = new In(args[0]);
        
        int key = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        
        int [] a = in.readAllInts(); 
        
        System.out.println(search(key, a, 0, a.length-1));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static int search(int key, int [] a, int lo, int hi)
    {
        int n = a.length;

        if (hi > lo)
        {
            int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
            if ((mid == n-1 || key < a[mid+1]) && a[mid] == key)
                return mid;
            else if (key < a[mid])
                return search(key, a, lo, (mid-1));
            else return search(key, a, (mid+1), hi);

        } else if(hi == lo && n == hi) {
            return -1*(lo);
        } else if(lo > hi) {
            return -1;
        }
        return -1*(lo-1);
    }
```

i've added 2 conditions:

1. when `hi==lo && hi == n` means that array's biggest value is less than key and `search()` returns highest index -(i)
2. when `lo > hi` means that array's lowest value is bigger than key and  `search()` returns -1

and edited all other conditions that are not met before
`return -1*(lo-1);` when `lo == hi` and `hi != n` then return previous index (i)

Comment: Worked like a charm! And your explanations were very comprehensive. Thanks so much for the help!